# How fscanf know this is the end of the line?

Tags: c

I read string from file if the string in the file is:

```
 "User1 User2 User3 User4 User5"
 "test1"
```

i want to read only the first line from the file,my code is:

```
 if (in_fp != NULL)
 {
   while (fscanf(in_fp, "%s", &user)!=EOF)
    {
      temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof user);
      strcpy(temp,user);
     }
 fclose (in_fp);
 }
```

but the problem is that fscanf read also that "test1" from the text file,i need to know how to make him to know that is the end of the line,what i need to fix in my code?
**i know about fgets** but i want to read each user separately

Comment: The `fscanf` function doesn't know about line endings. Read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: Oh, and you have lots of memory leaks in that code.

Comment: i edit my post right now,i know about fgets,i want to read each user separately to temp

Comment: You can combine e.g. `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a way

```
    if (in_fp != NULL){
        while (fscanf(in_fp, "%s%c", user, &ch)==2){
            temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof user);
            strcpy(temp, user);
            //do something
            printf("%s\n", user);
            free(temp);
            if(ch == '\n')
                break;
        }
        fclose (in_fp);
    }
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Nice.  I was going to amend my post about using `%c` or `%[]` to meet OP's goal, but I see you already nicely have such an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To use `fscanf("%s")` and variant formats is a tough way to solve this task.

The `%s` consumes leading whitespace including `' '` and `'\n'` indiscriminately, yet OP uses these 2 distinctly as a *username* delimiter and *record* delimiter.  Much better to read a line, using `fgets()` and then parse the buffer read.

OP is concerned about about unknown line length.  Whereas it is good to not limit code to only work with a short line, designing code to work with an endless line has a problem too.  Excessively long lines are increasing a sign of errant data or nefarious attempts to hack.  Better to allocate a big buffer and gracefully complain should a data file try to exceed it.

```
size_t N = 4096;
char *buffer = malloc(N);
if (buffer == NULL) ...
while (fgets(buffer, N, in_fp) != NULL) {
  size_t Len = strlen(buffer);
  if (Len == 0 || buffer[Len-1] != '\n) {
    HandleUnacceptbaleBuffer();
  }
  // parse buffer via sscanf, strtok, etc.
  char *p = buffer;
  int n
  while (1 == sscanf(p, "%s%n", &user, &n)) {
    Handle(user);
    p += n;
  }
}
free (buffer);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't.

And you don't want to use `scanf()` either. Avoid it like the plague.

If you want to read lines, then use `fgets()`. (Use it even if you don't want to read lines, still much better than `scanf()`).

---

I see the "but I want to read each word separately" question incoming. So, here you are:

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    // handle error
}

char *p = buf, *s = p;
while (p) {
    p = strtok_r(s, " ", &s);
    // do stuff with `p` if it's not NULL
}
```

Also, ***[do NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)***

Comment: thanks about your link.
i dont know the maximum length of the first line,thats why i use in fscanf,i need to read from the file and to stop when its the second line in the text thats what i need know

Comment: @user2976686 If the line is longer than `MAX_LINE` (which theoretically can't be the case), then either use `fread()` to read the entire file into memory and replace the first `'\n'` with a NUL character, or use dynamic memory allocation, exponential storage expansion and `fgetc()`.

Comment: ,hi,my problem is that i DONT KNOW what is the length of maximun line!

Comment: sorry but i still dont understand  your answer :(

Comment: getline() also works, and allocates the buffer for you.

Comment: @Demetri But that's not the reason for downvoting this (correct) answer. And `getline()` is not in the C standard library.

Comment: i don't did downvoting to the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 getline() is specified by POSIX and is part of glibc though